# How can I filter iTunes songs with spaces in them?

Tags: itunes, music, search

When I use the iTunes library text filter option to search for `love with`, I get the song `I'm in love with the hero` but also several hits for song titles where the words `love` or `with` appear separately. Is there any way to tell iTunes that I'm searching for a full string instead of separate words? If I enclose the search term in quotes like Google the filter doesn't return any hits, and the search question mark icon doesn't seem to have any other options that fields.

Comment: What if you search for "lovewith"?

Comment: Could create a Smart Playlist with two options - one searches the Title field for "love", the other for "with". Granted it's not a great repeat solution (since it's more time-consuming to modify the Smart Playlist settings than to type in the search bar) but as a one-off it will work.